# Use Event Sourcing to get rid of relational database?

Tags: database, orm, cqrs, relational, event-sourcing

I've read some articles about CQRS and Event Sourcing recently. While the first seemed to me like a highly complex and risky workaround to fix poorly performing business and poorly designed data access layers and data models, the last seemed like a solution to many problems.

**Problems to solve using Event Sourcing:**

1. Get rid of Relational Database and Object Relational Mappers, like NHibernate and Entity Framework. Hardly anybody in the programming area wants to pay attention to such stuff like indices, table/index fragmentation or normalization, how to design relational data and how to code/configure the ORM (a science on its own).
2. Have Business Model and in-memory "database" united, an entity/aggregate service keeping all relevant items in memory, maintaining integrity by simply dumping the CUD events somewhere without much pain. Old items can be evicted from memory and dumped to a NoSQL (or whatever) store and used for aggregate calculations, reporting, search and, if necessary, be re-activated. If I understand right, in-memory databases like VoltDB use event dumping in a similar way, but are still relational databases, separated from the business logic.
3. This would also make concurrency easier: instead of locking (with possible complete system deadlocks) or optimistic locking with a general "success or fail" logic, depending on whether the data has changed meanwhile (or rather complex DB code), merge rules can be implemented in code.
4. History: no more pain with implementing auditing functions, cemetary tables or "deleted" marker columns, or possibly deleted data still being required.
5. Data Duplication/Search/Reporting: use full-text indices instead of chasing missing relational indices, create proper viewing areas, preparing the data for the user in a required format, instead of using ugly copy routines in relational databases, with triggers, followup stored procedures or even program code copying data to half a dozen different tables.
6. Versioning: it's a pain to get many modules running with a number of different relational database versions, each having different tables and columns and needs appropriate ORM mappings. Could be much easier in a single layer model, with the event dump accepting any object format (typically schema-less or loose-schema NoSQL documents, represented as JSON or XML). It might also be possible to upgrade old data through a "data schema change event" chain (instead of having to maintain migration scripts for relational DBs).

**N-tier Business Model / Relational DB / ORM mess**

An n-tier approach a decade or longer ago might have been a business layer and data access layer. In order to keep separation really strict, many relational features were omitted, to implement them in the business layer instead: relational integrity, normalization, with the DB being what I call a "trash dump": looking like a kid playing around with SQL Server Management Studio or Access. Extremly un-normalized, polymorphic references ("Foreign Key" columns referencing different source tables, identified by a "ReferenceSource" marker), abuse of same tables for different kinds of business objects and duplication of data to numerous other tables (and from there again elsewhere), because performance wasnt good and this was supposed to improve queries. ORM usage was without object references too, reduced to single object load and save operations. Loading an aggregate (a graph of entities/table rows) would iterate through the graph and send a query for every set of sub-entities.

When performance got worse and, possibly, orphaned references caused serious trouble, attempts to implement classic relational design might have been made, but it was impossible to adapt the grown system to a complete data redesign (nobody would pay for it), hardly anybody would know how to map object relations or even optimized loading in the ORM. Such attempts were limited to a few places in the design, possibly making the data model and access even harder to maintain.

**CQRS on top of n-tier?**

To get acceptable performance, separate SQL queries were possibly built for certain modules, bypassing the business model with it's single object iterative access. This whole structure was suddenly called a de-facto CQRS, because of separate query access (which -could- have been handled by a well-implemented, relational data model and ORM usage, as long as it wasnt supposed to be a "Big data" Google- or Stackoverflow-like workload), and the plenty of duplicated data in relational tables, made up for immediate application access.

**Something better than the inappropriate table format?**

OK, so I read into CQRS, and while I didn't like the use of "CQRS" as described before, the concept of an event storage instead of a relational DB looked very useful: It is unlikely to successfully enforce the introduction of the original, state-of-art, relational DB design and OR mapping, and even if, it would be extremly costly. In fact, ordinary, object-oriented programming is much more "normalized" than most DB tables, due to the need to press all into the table format or create tons of tables for object graphs/aggregates. And I agree: having to take care of search indices and defragmentation, schema management and data history tracking manually, is like stone age IT, like running Ford T models and steam locomotives besides modern day cars and electric high speed trains.

**Any good Experiences?**

How are the experiences about using event sourcing (not necessarily full CQRS)? Does it eliminate much of the pain with relational databases? I really look forward for a kind of in-memory database with all business logic integrated, and possibly fast enough to make separate query modules dispensable!

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot going on in this question and so a specific, actionable answer is not possible, but if you're looking for one then it is...

**It depends on your domain.**

CQRS/ES/DDD is not appropriate for solving every single problem - it is not a silver bullet. If the domain suggests that CRUD/NTier will be good enough, then that's what you should use. All of the concerns you list in your question are infrastructural or system traits and say nothing about the very thing that should inform your choice of tool or practice; what are you trying to build?

Answer (score 3):

Although CQRS, ES, and DDD are very often used together they are separate concepts that are very powerful on their own.

**CQRS** (Command Query Responsibility Segregation): This is a very useful pattern to design software in general. The idea is to keep things that change state (commands) from things that do not (queries). In many systems queries modify the state of the database, this makes it very difficult for developers to reason about what is going on.

Imagine doing a query to find out some information and realizing that the information changed because you queried it.

CQRS prohibits those kind of behaviors. Commands (which cannot return information) change state and Queries (which return information) cannot modify state. That way, you have certainty in which parts of the code are idempotent (and therefore can be called as much as you want with no side effect) and which parts change state.

**DDD** (Domain Driven Design): This is a Design methodology for the "Data Structure" of the code. It does not prescribe techniques for database access or many technical details. What it does is provide guidelines and concepts to structure data in an application in a way that makes it much more responsive to the actual user's needs. It also simplifies development (although it is more work than just slapping something together).

**ES** (Event Sourcing): Event sourcing is a data storage strategy which shifts data storage from **state** (the actual values of a piece of data at the current point in time) into **transitions** (the changes that have happened to a piece of data during its lifetime) which are called **events**.

There are several advantages of using ES.

First, it allows the business to store much more information regarding what happened before (a boon to Data Scientists). In traditional systems, a lot of information is lost to updates of the data, and unless those updates are explicitly logged, the information is gone forever. This does not happen in ES.

Second, storing all events makes debugging much more simple because now a developer can follow the processing of the data since its beginning. An update to a piece of data that happened a long time ago (and would have been rewritten by another update and lost) but corrupted processing can be identified and fixed. Furthermore, the effects of the fix can even span all calculations that happened between the wrong event and the last event. In a traditional system, this would be impossible as we are only storing the latest state only.

While it is theoretically possible to write an Event Sourced system *without* CQRS or DDD, it is remarkably more difficult to do so.